# indicating a related field in a xml file

Tags: odoo-14

I have this xml fragment and it works

```
    <record id="expiry_alert" model="base.automation">
        <field name="name">XmlSend</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_project_task"/>
        <field name="trigger">on_time</field>
        <field name="active" eval="True"/>
        <field name="trg_date_id" search="[('model','=','project.task'),('name','=','date_deadline')]" />
        <field name="filter_domain">['&amp;',['date_deadline', '!=', False], ['stage_id.fold','=', False]]</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">record.expirations()</field>
        <field name="trg_date_range">5</field>
        <field name="trg_date_range_type">minutes</field>
    </record>
```

I say it works because it does insert a record in the base.automation model and such record does what I expected

Now, this version *doesn't* work

```
    <record id="expiry_alert" model="base.automation">
        <field name="name">XmlSend</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_project_task"/>
        <field name="trigger">on_time</field>
        <field name="active" eval="True"/>
        <field name="trg_date_id" ref="date_deadline" />       <-- PLEASE NOTE THIS LINE !!
        <field name="filter_domain">['&amp;',['date_deadline', '!=', False], ['stage_id.fold','=', False]]</field>
        <field name="state">code</field>
        <field name="code">record.expirations()</field>
        <field name="trg_date_range">5</field>
        <field name="trg_date_range_type">minutes</field>
    </record>
```

I tried with several variants of `<field name="trg_date_id" ref="date_deadline" />`,

like `<field name="trg_date_id" ref="project_task.date_deadline" />`

But I couldn't find a variant that works

Is it me ?
Is ref supported ?
How am I supposed to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the XML ID of the filed, activate developer mode and go to `settings -> technical -> fields`  and filter per Task model and search for date_deadline field, open it and from `debug icon` select `view Metadata`

The XML ID for date_deadline is `project.field_project_task__date_deadline`

So you can use it as below:

```
<field name="trg_date_id" ref="project.field_project_task__date_deadline" />
```